# CakePHP 2.x - Excel reader/writer integration

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Is anyone familiar with integrating Excel reader/writer export in CakePHP 2.x? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!
Peace. xD

Comment: Please, ask a correct question. What is the task? What do you need? And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest answer is:

Download PHPExcel from https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/119187

Extract the content of *Classes* folder to `app/Vendor` directory.

In your controller create function something like:

```
public function toExcel(){
    App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel', array('file' => 'PHPExcel.php'));
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->removeSheetByIndex(0);

    // You code is here

    // Save to file
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $fileNameWithPath = TMP.'reports/test.xlsx';

    $objWriter->save($fileNameWithPath);

    // Response - let user download it
    $this->response->file($fileNameWithPath, array('download' => true, 'name' => $fileName));
    return $this->response;

}
```

Read the [Documentation](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/documentation) to get know what do to next